# Masking an Image

Tags: css, masking

[image: I]

I am trying to make this image using css with 2 masks, but i am getting absolutely nowhere.
Ive tried to use the code example from this page:

http://www.ajaxandicons.com/2010/04/image-masking-with-css/

My two images are:

[image]

and

[image]

I cant get it to work for the life of me.  Can someone jsfiddle or put a working result here showing me how to properly mask the image?

Comment: What is the transparent colour in your mask, the black or the white? What doesn't work? Can you show what you have right now, preferably in a JSFiddle?

Comment: What do you mean with 'masking'?

Comment: @Pekka Look at the three images ... the transparent color is black

Comment: @belisarius but that won't work, at least not without browser-specific shenanigans

Comment: @Pekka Right. I was just pointing out the "transparent color" part of your previous question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask this in Safari and Chrome using the `-webkit-mask` CSS3 property like so ([see fiddle in Safari/Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/fvnyQ/)):

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJUzS.jpg" 
     style="-webkit-mask:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KEpA.png')" />
```

However, to do a cross-browser implementation your mask will need alpha transparency in the black section of your .png image and then overlay the mask using CSS position.

Comment: why would i need to add positioning? And how can i put transparency in the black when im looking for the black trapezoid shape to cut out the image? I dont follow

Comment: @Willing if you want your image to work across browsers, you need your mask to have real alpha transparency, not black. That is the core issue here

Comment: is there a way to make this work in firefox and ie the way it works in safari and chrome?

Comment: @mVChr, What do you mean by "Real Alpha Transparency"? Could you please make us a cross-browser example in 'jsfiddle.net'? Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to achieve this? http://jsfiddle.net/6dRSh/

**html**

```
<div id="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJUzS.jpg">
    <div id="mask"><img src="http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/4645/4kepa.png" ></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#image {position:relative;}
#mask {position:absolute; top:0;}
```