# css triangle mask

Tags: css, image, mask

I would like to create a theme for tumblr where two images are overlayed to appear as one image. The two images would be positioned one on top of the other with the top image masked in the shape of a triangle.

Here is a photoshop mockup of what I am hoping to achieve: http://s3.amazonaws.com/data.tumblr.com/tumblr_l6w6w3sdM51qa49m9o1_1280.png?AWSAccessKeyId=0RYTHV9YYQ4W5Q3HQMG2&Expires=1298329479&Signature=cUcRVwOWEp6m%2BDDnJgTs81rhPxA%3D

The only bit I am unsure about is the masking of the triangle image. Not sure if it is possible... Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978958/masking-an-image/4979058

Comment: This type of thing is what I am hoping to achieve: http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/ Looks like it is only for chrome and safari though.

Answer (score 2):

For cross browser compatibility, you need to create your mask as a transparent image in the shape you like. See my link below. I create a triangular mask in photoshop and applied it to an image.

## Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/39VG9/1/

Comment: Nice try, but sometimes it's important to have the outer form transparent.