# How to mask divs with a linear gradient mask?

Tags: html, css, masking

I'm trying to fade a `div`'s content out at the edges using a couple of absolutely positioned overlay `div`s at either side. However, I need the background of the page to be viewable once the fade is finished, and throughout - effectively masking the content of one `div` using 2 others with linear 'fade' gradients. See the diagram below for a better explanation...

[image: Page div wireframe]

I have tried the following:

- Use `-webkit-mask` property with a linear gradient. This works in Webkit, but nothing else. Also, the linear gradient is rather choppy and stacatto when used with the mask property. Not ideal.
- Use SVG gradient mask (e.g. [in the Firefox / MDN demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example:.C2.A0Masking)). Works, but only in Firefox. Not anywhere near as poor a gradient as `-webkit-mask` / `linear-gradient` in Chrome though
- Using a transparent masking GIF or PNG. However, in the example I used the masking colour shows through (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385864/can-webkit-mask-work-on-an-element-eg-div)).

I'm hoping there might be another way that I've not thought of, or perhaps an alternative layout I could use to achieve the same aim. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: `webkit-mask' has choppy gradients, as mentioned in my post, but it's pretty close. SVG looks better, but suffers the same x-browser support issues. The transparent mask setup I attempted only works by showing content through transparent pixels and hiding it with any other colour, whereas I want the 'any other colour' to be whatever is in the background.

Comment: But yes, I tried all 3 options, which is why I know what they do and how they're inadequate for my purposes.

Comment: I'd love feedback on how to rephrase this given the close votes. This is a genuine problem I've tried to solve myself unsuccessfully.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that the transparent PNG would be the best bet, make it absolute with a higher z index and make it inside a container div. This container div would float over the background sliding image? I would use a very small 2 px slice and just repeat it along the y axis, but I might not be seeing your problem correctly.

I tried it with a very small slice of the radiant that I repeated down (y) and the underlying image did scroll through the top transparent images. If I follow what you are trying to do.   It worked in chrome, firefox and safari: here is the css

```
#container {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url(Untitled-1.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
clear: both;
float: left;
height: 768px;
width: 80000px;
position: relative;
}
#container #info {
float: left;
width: 630px;
margin-right: 20%;
margin-left: 20%;
position: fixed;
margin-top: 100px;
height: 519px;
clear: both;
clip: rect(100px,auto,auto,auto);
 }
#container #info #l_side {
background-image: url(left_.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
float: left;
height: 519px;
width: 165px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -2px;
}
#container #info #content {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.56);
color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.56);
float: left;
height: 519px;
width: 300px;
position: relative;
}
#container #info #r_side {
background-image: url(Right.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
float: left;
height: 519px;
width: 165px;
position: relative;
margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've given this a shot (if I understand you correctly), but the transparent div doesn't allow both the 'gradual fade out' of the content, whilst still allowing the background to show through.