# How Do I Mask or Clip an Image in CSS

Tags: css

The situation:

I'm in bootstrap so everything has to responsive to the column container.

I have images that are 16:9 ratio and want to clip them to be around 40:27, remaining responsive as stated before.

I've investigated clipping and masking and so far, from the perspective of my research at least, neither is going to work without writing new clipping based on site width and since I'm going for a totally fluid site this isn't an option.

Any ideas?

Additional info:  the source images are ALWAYS 1920x1080

**UPDATED:** I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sckdd6hq/1/ with the thinking that:

standin.png forces the container size, background image should be 'sizable' to fit within.  So the question now is how do I get the background size to be the right height and then center it in the resulting container?

Here's the html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flexcon">
<img src="http://s28.postimg.org/l0hz0do5p/standin.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.flexcon { 
    background-image: url("http://s1.postimg.org/ffw8n4yjz/Google_Logo_Loop_GIF_01.gif");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container { 
width: 400px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post one image you want to mask in bootstrap with the CSS your using?

Comment: Sure.  Added Bat Man!

Comment: Added some additional info... source image is always 1920x1080

Comment: Providing the CSS is infinitely more important than a stock image.

Comment: Related (if not dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978958/masking-an-image

Comment: Not really a dupe, I'm not sure if masking is even what I need but the question you directed me to makes me think it probably is not..  The goal is to convert the image to the proper aspect ratio.  Haven't found a css solution that works so I have no css to offer.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle.  I think I'm getting close, down to how do I clip the background image to fit the container without 'stretching' it...

Comment: Is it possible you add the images as `background-image` in css with `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with CSS clip, and quite honestly I doubt there's a RELIABLE pure CSS way to do it, but here you have a pretty close alternative.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fakecell"></div>
    <div class="flexcon">
        <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/ffw8n4yjz/Google_Logo_Loop_GIF_01.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.fakecell {
    padding-top: 6.75%;
    /* 40:27 aspect ratio */
}
.flexcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.flexcon img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgugypwd/1/)